# Pyserial write function is throwing an exception after sending some data

Tags: python, pyserial

Pyserial write function is throwing an exception after sending some data. If I don’t set the `write_timeout` variable, it won’t throw the exception but it’ll block the program. This is the exception I’m getting:

> serial_node.py", line 29, in send
>       raise e SerialTimeoutException: Write timeout

Is there a way to fix this? I’m sending serial data to an Arduino Due through its native serial port.

Best,

Comment: It would help to see your code and what's at the other end (where are you sending data). You are probably closing the port before completing the writing or the device at the other end is resetting itself while you are trying to write.

Comment: Could be an incorrect flow control setting, preventing any data from actually being sent to the device.  Once the buffer fills up, you won't be able to send anything else.